# Console Log multiple entries & DOM entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry for asking this question but its better I clear my mind off it. I have added console log in two section of my code. When i navigate back and forth each posts, the different logs gets appended each time even if I am clicking on the same posts multiple times. I hope this is not an indication that my DOM is getting filled up even though I have added .empty() function in the code hoping that this would simply clear the console log and append new clicks. Screen shot below:

[image]

Sections of the code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function() {     

    $('#postlist').html();  
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/?json=recentstories",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); },
            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },

            success:function (data){

                console.log(data);
                $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {

                var result = $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: val.title}),$("<p>", {html: val.excerpt})]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');
                $('#postlist').append(result);
                return (key !== 4);

            });

            $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');

function showPost(id) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Loading", false);
    console.log(id);
    $('#mypost').empty();
    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        var posts='';
```

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, console.log will break ie8, so be sure to remove it before pushing to your live environment.

Comment: Only using it to debug and to be sure everything is working as expected

Comment: You can eventually write `console = console || {log:function(){}};` to not break any browser.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `console.clear()` you can run.

Also, you might be interested in `console.table(data.posts)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `empty()` will do nothing to the console, since jQuery works on the DOM and has nothing to do with the console. The standard behavior of the console is to keep appending data (that way you have a history of your logging). You can try using `console.clear()`, but it is not supported in all browsers. I do believe Chrome and newer versions of FireBug support it, though.

Comment: OK guys my understanding now is this as nothing to do with the DOM. Whilst this is the case, how do I confirm how much is in the DOM at any point in time

Comment: Are you looking for the number of specific elements in the DOM? You can just use `jQuery(...).length` (where `...` is a selector).

Comment: Yes, I will research on this.